# How to integrate a python script (using Pandas ,numpy and various other 3rd party libraries) into a C# application?

Tags: python, c#, pandas, winforms, numpy

I am trying to integrate a python script with below mentioned libraries into a C# application.

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import pyodbc
import calendar as cd
from datetime import datetime
#import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import filedialog
from scipy.stats import poisson
```

I have tried using Iron python to make a call to python script which works fine in case of a normal py script. However when tried with the above mentioned libraries gives error - $exception {"No module named pandas"} Python.IronRuntime.Exceptions.ImportException

```
//instance of python engine
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            //reading code from file
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Calc_model.py"));
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            //executing script in scope
            source.Execute(scope);
```

Would appreciate your inputs. Many Thanks.

Comment: It appears you need to use pip with IronPython: https://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html .  IronPython has no idea about those pip modules and apparently does not execute python scripts using the same installation on your machine.  IronPython has documentation on that process it looks like.

Comment: did you find any solution?